# PCA in Sklearn: Uncorrelated Outputs

Tags: python, pca, scikit-learn

Admittedly I am now questioning my understanding of the output from PCA in sklearn.

At a high level, many tutorials discuss the benefits of PCA as having uncorrelated components for use in downstream tasks.  However, PCA in sklearn has a parameter `whiten` which is `False` by default.

My question: Are the components returned by the **default behavior** of PCA in sklearn correlated, and only uncorrelated if we use the `whiten=True` parameter?  And to clarify, I am referring to the components that are returned with `.transform` or `.fit_transform`.

If the default behavior returns orthogonal components, my follow on here is to understand the behavior of `whiten=True` at a high level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By construction, "default" PCA (in scikit-learn or otherwise) *always* returns *uncorrelated* components.

[Whitening](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/tutorial/unsupervised/PCAWhitening/) also ensures that the different components of PCA have [unit variance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/95814/159540); this can be useful [to improve the predictive accuracy of some algorithms](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/326693/159540).

To summarise:

> whitening = decorrelation (e.g. PCA) + normalisation

But PCA can be performed on its own and does produce uncorrelated components.

What can be confusing is scikit-kearn's `whiten` description:

> When True (False by default) the components_ vectors are multiplied by
> the square root of n_samples and then divided by the singular values
> to ensure uncorrelated outputs with unit component-wise variances.

The word `uncorrelated` should be removed for clarity (as the decorrelation comes from PCA, not from setting `whiten` to `True`).

Comment: Awesome answer. The docs should be updated. The only thing whitening does is return components with unit variance. If your model doesn't need unit variance for each feature (neural nets do, but tree-based models don't) then you can leave whiten=False.